# SpringBoot2.4.4 Junit5 with JaCoco test coverage is not shown

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, jacoco

i am using junit5 with springboot 2.4.4 version. I have integrated jacoco for the test coverage. However my test gets passed but coverage is not shown in it.

Here i am mention a demo class of the concept what i am implemented

```
public class Calculator {

  public int sum() {
    return sumPrivate();
  }

  private int sumPrivate() {
    return 100;
  }
}
```

And this is test class of it

```
public class CalculatorTest {
  
  @Test
  public void test() {
    assertNotNull(new Calculator().sum());
  }
}
```

i have debugged my class private method gets called but not shown in jacoco code coverage.

And here is my plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                            <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
                            <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                    <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
                    <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
                    <output>file</output>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify goal `check` after `test` in-order to check coverage.
If you also need to generate report then goal is `report`

[Here](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) are all the possible goals. Got to the end of page.

```xml
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>coverage-validation</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <rule>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <minimum>0.90</minimum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
              </rules>
              <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
            </configuration>

          </execution>
        </executions>
```